# Control audio playback using mouse only?

Tags: windows-vista, software-rec, audio, mouse

When listing to music on laptop, with the lid closed, the only control available is through mouse.

I'm looking for a software that I can use to map different audio playback features to mouse buttons, for example, left button: pause/play, right button: next song, scroll:volume level, .etc...

A somewhat necessary feature would be stopping any other work of the mouse, so when I click left button, for example, nothing gets clicked in other programs.

Is there any solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the keyboard shortcuts for those features, you can enable an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script before closing the lid that will do all the remapping.

Example:

```
LButton::Up
```

If your specific media player can increase volume via the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow key, this will let you use your left mouse button instead. This will override your default mouse behavior, so you don't have to worry about clicking in other applications. Just make sure your media player has focus and your script is enabled when you close the lid.

Remapping guide found [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).